# Problem during Gnocchi installation for ceilometer (Pike) over Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: openstack

I am trying to install OpenStack (Pike) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have already installed basic modules of OpenStack like compute, image, glance, keystone, cinder, Horizon by following guidelines available on link: https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/. I have followed it completely, except installing Pike instead of Queen.

Now I am trying to install Ceilometer by following link: https://docs.openstack.org/ceilometer/pike/install/install-base-ubuntu.html, but Once I try to install Gnocchi, it gives error. which is as follows. Please guide in simple and definite steps, as I am quite novice in Linux and OpenStack.

```
Creating config file /etc/dbconfig-common/gnocchi-common.conf with new version  
granting access to database gnocchidb for gnocchi-common@localhost: success.  
verifying access for gnocchi-common@localhost: success.  
creating database gnocchidb: success.  
verifying database gnocchidb exists: success.  
dbconfig-common: flushing administrative password  
Now calling gnocchi-upgrade: this may take a while...  
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:820: UserWarning: Could not find matplotlibrc; using defaults  
  warnings.warn('Could not find matplotlibrc; using defaults')  
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:974: UserWarning: could not find rc file; returning defaults  
  warnings.warn(message)  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/bin/gnocchi-upgrade", line 10, in <module>  
    sys.exit(upgrade())  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnocchi/cli.py", line 62, in upgrade
    conf = service.prepare_service(conf=conf)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnocchi/service.py", line 60, in prepare_service  
    version=pbr.version.VersionInfo('gnocchi').version_string())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py", line 2471, in __call__  
    self._check_required_opts()  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py", line 3129, in _check_required_opts
    raise RequiredOptError(opt.name, group)  
oslo_config.cfg.RequiredOptError: value required for option url in group [indexer]  
dpkg: error processing package gnocchi-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1  
Setting up python-openstacksdk (0.9.13-0ubuntu1~cloud0) ...  
Setting up python-openstackclient (3.8.1-0ubuntu3~cloud0) ...  
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python2-openstack to provide /usr/bin/openstack (openstack) in auto mode    
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnocchi-api:
 gnocchi-api depends on gnocchi-common (= 3.1.2-0ubuntu1~cloud0); however:
  Package gnocchi-common is not configured yet.  

dpkg: error processing package gnocchi-api (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.  
                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnocchi-metricd:
 gnocchi-metricd depends on gnocchi-common (= 3.1.2-0ubuntu1~cloud0); however:
  Package gnocchi-common is not configured yet.  

dpkg: error processing package gnocchi-metricd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.  
                            Setting up libaec0:amd64 (0.3.2-1) ...  
Setting up libamd2.4.1:amd64 (1:4.4.6-1) ...  
Setting up libglpk36:amd64 (4.57-1build3) ...  
Setting up libgsl2:amd64 (2.1+dfsg-2) ...  
Setting up libsz2:amd64 (0.3.2-1) ...  
Setting up libhdf5-10:amd64 (1.8.16+docs-4ubuntu1) ...  
Setting up libjs-jquery-ui (1.10.1+dfsg-1) ...  
Setting up python-antlr (2.7.7+dfsg-6ubuntu1) ...  
Setting up python-cairo (1.8.8-2) ...  
Setting up libdsdp-5.8gf (5.8-9.1ubuntu2) ...  
Setting up python-cvxopt (1.1.4-1.4) ...    
Setting up python-cycler (0.9.0-1) ...  
Setting up python-egenix-mxtools (3.2.9-1) ...  
Setting up python-egenix-mxdatetime (3.2.9-1) ...  
Setting up python-gobject-2 (2.28.6-12ubuntu1) ...  
Setting up python-gtk2 (2.24.0-4ubuntu1) ...  
Setting up python-glade2 (2.24.0-4ubuntu1) ...  
Setting up python-gnocchiclient (3.1.1-0ubuntu2~cloud0) ...  
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python2-gnocchi to provide /usr/bin/gnocchi (gnocchi) in auto mode  
Setting up python-imaging (3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1) ...  
Setting up python-jdcal (1.0-1build1) ...  
Setting up python-joblib (0.9.4-1) ...  
Setting up ttf-bitstream-vera (1.10-8) ...  
Setting up python-matplotlib-data (1.5.1-1ubuntu1) ...  
Setting up python-matplotlib (1.5.1-1ubuntu1) ...  
Setting up python-nose (1.3.7-1) ...  
Setting up python-numexpr (2.4.3-1ubuntu1) ...  
Setting up python-openpyxl (2.3.0-1) ...  
Setting up python-patsy (0.4.1-2) ...  
Setting up python-py (1.4.32-3~cloud0) ...  
Setting up python-pytest (3.0.6-1~cloud0) ...  
Setting up libsnappy1v5:amd64 (1.1.3-2) ...  
Setting up python-tables-lib (3.2.2-2) ...  
Setting up python-tables-data (3.2.2-2) ...  
Setting up python-tables (3.2.2-2) ...  
Setting up python-tk (2.7.11-2) ...  
Setting up python-xlrd (0.9.4-1) ...  
Setting up python-xlwt (0.7.5+debian1-1) ...  
Setting up python-statsmodels-lib (0.6.1-4) ...  
Setting up python-statsmodels (0.6.1-4) ...  
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 gnocchi-common  
 gnocchi-api  
 gnocchi-metricd  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)  

ProblemType: Package  
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 16.04  
Package: gnocchi-common 3.1.2-0ubuntu1~cloud0 [origin: Canonical]  
ProcVersionSignature: Ubuntu 4.10.0-28.32~16.04.2-generic 4.10.17  
Uname: Linux 4.10.0-28-generic x86_64  
ApportVersion: 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.12  
Architecture: amd64  
CrashDB:  
 {
                "impl": "launchpad",
                "project": "cloud-archive",
                "bug_pattern_url": "http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/bugpatterns/bugpatterns.xml",
             }  
Date: Thu Nov 16 16:11:19 2017  
ErrorMessage: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1  
InstallationDate: Installed on 2017-11-15 (0 days ago)  
InstallationMedia: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS "Xenial Xerus" - Release amd64 (20170801)  
PackageArchitecture: all  
RelatedPackageVersions:  
 dpkg 1.18.4ubuntu1.2
 apt 1.2.24
SourcePackage: gnocchi  
Title: package gnocchi-common 3.1.2-0ubuntu1~cloud0 [origin: Canonical] failed to install/upgrade: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1  
UpgradeStatus: No upgrade log present (probably fresh install)
```

Answer (score 0):

To correct these problems you must activate the OpenStack repository by following the steps below:

```
apt install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository cloud-archive:pike
apt update && apt dist-upgrade
```

Reference link:

https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/environment-packages-ubuntu.html